# How to overridess default element.styles

Tags: css, element, default

I'm using AJAX calendar extender, for some reason i want to use my own CSS style. and i tried to position the popup calendar but browser always take the element.styles and my CSS is not working. So how to do overrides the default element styles?

Answer (score 0):

[`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)